# Can I modify the status value of a key within a mouse event handler?

Tags: javascript

For some purpose, I need something in javascript like this:

```
function onMouseDown(e) {//mouse event handler 
  e.shiftKey = true;
}
```

But this seems doesn't work, shiftKey still keeps it's original value after **e.shiftKey = true**.

I am using a third party model, there is already a mouse event handler, but the function in it requires the shift key down, but I don't want it as a condition.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Don't think its possible. The click event also doesnt have a parameter 'shiftkey'

Comment: `e` is a mouseDown event and afaik doesn't have a shiftKey property. That's reserved for `keypress`, `keydown` and `keyup` events. Even if you change that for that event, it will not 'magically' be true for the next event. The best thing you can probably do is make a global variable and set that to true, and check that in your key-events.

Comment: You can use `new Event` in browsers that support it: http://jsfiddle.net/w4kP9/